# Алгоритм симметричной комбинации

Tags: java, алгоритм

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, как составить алгоритм по заданию или блок-схему?

Задание:

> Электронные часы показывают время в формате от 00:00 до 23:59. Подсчитать сколько раз за сутки случается так, что слева от двоеточия показывается симметричная комбинация для той, что справа от двоеточия (например, 02:20, 11:11 или 15:51).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Т.к. комбинаций не очень много, задачу можно решить полным перебором.
Приведу код на C++, но думаю его можно будет легко адаптировать для Java:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

class Time {
public:
    Time(int h, int m)
        : h_(h), m_(m)
    {}

    bool operator==(const Time& t) const {
        return h_ == t.h_ && m_ == t.m_;
    }

    bool operator!=(const Time& t) const {
        return !(*this == t);
    }

    Time& operator++() {
        if (++m_ == 60) {
            m_ = 0;
            if (++h_ == 24) {
                h_ = 0;
            }
        }
        return *this;
    }

    bool isSymetric() const {
       int d1 = h_ / 10;
       int d2 = h_ % 10;
       int d3 = m_ / 10;
       int d4 = m_ % 10;
       return d1 == d4 && d2 == d3;
    }

    int h() const {
        return h_;
    }

    int m() const {
        return m_;
    }

private:
    int h_;
    int m_;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Time& time) {
    char prev = os.fill('0');
    os << std::setw(2) << time.h() << ':' << std::setw(2) << time.m();
    os.fill(prev);
    return os;
}

int main() {
    Time time(0, 0);
    do {
        if (time.isSymetric()) {
            std::cout << time << std::endl;
        }
    } while (++time != Time(0, 0));
}
```

Результат:

```
00:00
01:10
02:20
03:30
04:40
05:50
10:01
11:11
12:21
13:31
14:41
15:51
20:02
21:12
22:22
23:32
```

Answer (score 3):

Получается, что комбинация симетрической может только когда внутренняя цифра (та, которая возле двоеточия) меньше шести - имеем [00;05]U[10;15]U[20;23] => 6+6+4 = 16 раз. Хотя может быть какой-то более изящный метод.

Answer (score 2):

кажется проще некуда, цикл на 24 итерации

```
  int x, y;
  final StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder ( 5 );

  // for each hour: reverse hour value to get minutes
  for ( int i = 0; i < 24; i++ ) // hours 0-23
  {
     x = i / 10;
     y = i % 10;

     // filter invalid minutes value
     if ( y > 5 )
     {
        continue;
     }

     // [10*x]+[y]:[10*y]+[x]
     b.append ( x ).append ( y ).append ( ":" ).append ( y ).append ( x );

     System.out.println ( b );
     b.setLength ( 0 );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 int b=0;
    for (int h = 0; h < 24; h++){
        for (int m = 0; m < 60; m++){
            if (h%10 == m/10 && h/10 == m%10){
            b++;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(b);
}
```

}

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]